# Magento - Get the associated product attributes of an item in the wishlist

Tags: php, magento, model, magento-1.9

In app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php, I am trying to get the attribute values of an associated product within the wishlist.  I've attempted several approaches but I can only seem to produce data for the parent product.

Latest attempt

```
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    if($customer->getId()) {
        $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);
        $wishListItemCollection = $wishlist->getItemCollection();
        foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $wlitem) {
            $wishitem = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($wlitem->getStoreId())->load($wlitem->getProductId());
            //echo $wishitem->getId() . '<br>';
            if($product->getId() == $wishitem->getId()) { //if the current product id equals the wishlist product id
                echo $wishitem->getSku()."</br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

That only gets me the parent product's sku.  What I ultimately want to get is the attribute value for 2 attributes that I added for configurable products (not super attributes) but it seems that $product in Price.php only has the parent product collection.

Other Attempts:

```
            $item_s = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->loadWithOptions($product->getId(), 'simple_product')->getOptionsByCode();
            $simple_product = $item_s['simple_product']->getData();
            $simple_product_id = $simple_product['product_id'];
            $sim_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simple_product_id);
            print_r($sim_product);
```

This only resulted in an error on the page.

Also:

```
    $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    //echo $_item->getData('ppuom');
    //print_r($_item);
    $simpleProduct = $_item->getOptionsByCode()['simple_product']->getItem()->getProduct();
    print_r($simpleProduct);
```

Comment: What other attempts have you made?

Comment: @berg37 I will update my question with other attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as if you were most of the way there.  I've tested this on my Magento site and it worked for me.  It's pretty simple actually, you just have to grab the right model for that collection.  Also, it seems like you're changing the pricing?!?!  Be careful that your wishlist items contain the necessary attributes used in your logic.

```
$_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$attribute1 = $_item->getData('attribute1_code'); //see admin for attribute code
$attribute2 = $_item->getData('attribute2_code'); //see admin for attribute code
```

**OR**

Make changes to your template's wishlist files rather than the pricing logic in the code folder.  You'll have access to all the data you need and it won't interfere with the price.php file which is relied on heavily in the cart and other critical areas of the website.  The price in the wishlist is recalculated when it's moved to the cart anyway.

Comment: Hmmm... I will try this but it looks like this will just return the attribute values for the parent product.  I am looking for the child product values.

Comment: This is indeed getting the values for the configurable (parent) product, not the associated (child) product.  Do you have another solution?

Comment: Rather than messing with Price.php... why don't you mess with the wishlist template?  ALl the information you need for the product/item should be readily available to you.  Then, if the customer adds the item to the cart, your Price.php file will do the math accordingly.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Good point.  I suppose the wishlist price is just for vanity now that you mention it.